# How can i refresh selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Above image is what i want

this is my code

```
    URL = 'ABC'
    A = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#reser2 > ul > li') << (it will be apple when it is)
    driver.get(URL)

    while True :
        if A.text != "APPLE":
            driver.get(URL)
            time.sleep(0.7)
        else :
            break
```

but when there is no element. that time the error is appeared.

"no such element"

if there is no element, loop refresh until it will be appeared

Answer (score 0):

- Wait until the element is found.

```py
 A = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#reser2 > ul > li')))
```

Answer (score 0):

selenium refresh:

```
driver.refresh()
```

And try to add waiting for element show.